# Missing "Add as Link" in "Add Existing Item" for Visual Studio 2015 Shared projects

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

**Context:**

Classic project types have an "Add as Link" option in the "Add Existing Item" dialog. This allows one file to be shared across multiple projects, by adding the file to the project without physically copying the file to the project directory. This button is missing from the Add Existing Item dialog for Shared projects. See exhibit below.

***Note***: *This is not such new ASP 5 project with "project.json". There is no "project.json", Project files are XML though named* *.projitems, *their XML schema is very similar to* *.csproj*

**Question:**

In my solution there are multiple shared projects. I would like to have a single common solution level file (such as SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs) linked into each one. How can I accomplish this task?

**Exhibit:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think at the moment the only way to solve this is to edit the `.projitems` files manually.

For each shared project edit the related `.projitem` manually. Look for the `ItemGroup` element where all the `Compile` elements are located and add the following:

```xml
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)PathToYourSolutionAssemblyRelativeToThisFileDirectory\SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs" >
  <Link>YourDesiredFolderPathInSolutionExplorer\SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

`$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` as the name implies is the path of the current `.projitems` file. So if your shared projects are located on different file system folders than this path is resolved differently for each `.projitems` file. So you have to replace `PathToYourSolutionAssemblyRelativeToThisFileDirectory` with the correct relative path to your `SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs` for each `.projitems` file.